# How to Load data in PIG from the file which has semicolon as a delimiter

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

i am using following command to load data

```
A = LOAD '*Myfilepath*' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage(';', 'YES_MULTILINE', 'NOCHANGE', 'SKIP_INPUT_HEADER') AS (a:chararray, b:int, c:chararray);
```

But its not working .

Comment: Please clarify "not working"

Answer (score 0):

Please change the following in your code

**From:** USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage(**';'**, 'YES_MULTILINE', 'NOCHANGE', 'SKIP_INPUT_HEADER')

**TO:** USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage(**','**, 'YES_MULTILINE', 'NOCHANGE', 'SKIP_INPUT_HEADER')

csv is a "," comma separated file and not semicolon ";" seperated file

Hope this helps!!!....

Answer (score 0):

If it's a clean file with no inverted comma hiccups , this is good :

```
A = LOAD '*Myfilepath*' USING PigStorage(';') AS (a:chararray, b:int, c:chararray);
```

In your case , I think you have not registered the piggybank jar before using its attributes ! Download the JAR and register as shown below :

```
REGISTER '/export/home/piggybank.jar';
A = LOAD 'sam3.txt' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage(';', 'YES_MULTILINE', 'NOCHANGE', 'SKIP_INPUT_HEADER') AS (a:chararray, b:int, c:chararray);
```

NOTE : when you use `LOAD '*Myfilepath*'`  , this picks all the files in that directory ! In this case , `'SKIP_INPUT_HEADER'` isn't effective !